# VB 6.0 Add new record raises error object variable or With block not set

Tags: vb6

I want to add a new record to my database on the form load event - that is, as soon as my form loads the text box will be blank, which will enable the user to input info that will then be added to the database. 
When my code is this, however:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Data1.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error:

> run-time error '91'; object variable or With block not set.
>   what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

place your code in  Form_Initialize()

```
Private Sub Form_Initialize()
Data1.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think; You need to change it to something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = Data1.Recordset

    rs.AddNew
    rs!Column1 = 1
    rs!Column2 = "test
    rs.Update

End Sub
```

Now, If you have the error message over `Set rs = Data1.Recordset` then we need to know what is `Data1`.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `adodc1.refresh` before `addnew` line. It will solve it.